# I'm writing an Android module for trigger io that requires an activity be created, forge inspector can't find the activity

Tags: android, eclipse, trigger.io

I'm writing a custom Android native module that needs to create an activity. I've added the activity to my ForgeModule project AndroidManifest.xml, but when I run the ForgeInspector project, ForgeInspector cannot find the activity when I start the intent.

Is there something special I need to do to get my module's manifest to get incorporated in the final product?

Here is the error when the intent is used to start the activity.

```
12-05 13:44:56.493: D/Forge(3867): Returned: {"content":{"message":"Forge Java error: ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {io.trigger.forge.android.inspector/io.filepicker.FilePicker}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?","type":"UNEXPECTED_FAILURE","subtype":null,"full_error":"android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {io.trigger.forge.android.inspector/io.filepicker.FilePicker}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?\n\tat android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1556)\n\tat android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)\n\tat android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3391)\n\tat android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3352)\n\tat io.trigger.forge.android.modules.filepicker.API.importFile(API.java:26)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)\n\tat io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeApp.callJavaFromJavaScript(ForgeApp.java:316)\n\tat io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeJSBridge$1.run(ForgeJSBridge.java:25)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)\n"},"callid":"3AF217BD-F5B7-4873-A47F-CE3BF6D53214","status":"error"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly define the intent-filters and actions in the ForgeModule project AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I didn't define any intent filters or actions. Could that result in an activity not found error? I've updated the question with the error message.

Comment: You have to declare the Activity and the intent-filters in the AndroidManifest.xml file. That's how android finds the other Activities which can perform certain actions. Read the following http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html.